# App crashes on launch -- iTunes (ios)

Tags: ios, crash, itunes, launch

I recently submitted my app to apple. I've done testing on this app both on the new xcode version/iphone simulator, iphone 4 with 4.2 AND 5.0.1 update. And the app does not crash or anything. In fact it runs very smoothly.

iTunes quickly rejected my app according to them:

"We found that your app crashed on iPhone 4 running iOS 5.0.1, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Your app crashed on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks immediately after launch."

But I've tested my app and it works fine and smoothly on the phones.

They also sent me the reports:

```
Date/Time:       2011-12-07 14:40:19.619 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/A9CB8E5C-2491-42E1-8E5E-2033D7E9838D/SSRWheels.app> (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x340888bf 0x354a31e5 0x340887b9 0x340887db 0x327ec747 0x327edbb9 0x32726a45 0x325b0227 0x325aa313 0x32578921 0x325783bf 0x32577d2d 0x308cadf3 0x3405c553 0x3405c4f5 0x3405b343 0x33fde4dd 0x33fde3a5 0x325a9457 0x325a6743 0x100723 0x1006dc)
```

I've re-checked my work. And the only error message (not crashing) I get was needing a rootviewcontroller when the app start. I fixed that problem by taking off the UIAlertView that pops up when my app loads up. The error code does not show anymore...

Could that be the problem?

Anyone have any advice?

Thank you so much...

Comment: Can't you just re-submit your app to Apple?

Comment: Does you project actually contain a `MainWindow.xib`? If not, why are you referencing it within the `info.plist`?

Comment: They had sent me the same thing for 1 of my apps. I tested and tested and tested (on multiple devices) but I could not get it to crash where they said it crashing (or at all for that matter). So I literally resubmitted the app without changing a line of code and said to apple "I believe I have corrected the issue". 2 Days later they approved it and put it in the app store. ?? Not sure what happened there?

Comment: lol... im testing and testing also. I will try that and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed a NIB name during development, the NIB cache means that incorrect references to the old NIB name will still work *on devices that have previously had the app installed*. This could lead to the situation you describe—works fine for you, but crashes for the app store testers because it is a fresh install. And the error message would be similar to what they are reporting.

Delete your app completely off a test device, do a clean build, reinstall the app, and see if you can reproduce the error.

Comment: I didn't change any NIB name. After testing and testing I got an error... updating my original post.

Comment: Okay, nm on that error... my app works and installs on 2 5.0 devices and 4.2 device. They run smooth and well... I can't find anything regarding crashes. It's making me crazy lol

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your app only works when some specific value is in `NSUserDefaults`.

Be sure to test it after removing all your `NSUserDefaults`, best to do that by deleting the app off the device and then re-installing a clean release build.